# Erro "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type"

Tags: json, api, vb.net, get, webrequest

Galera, estou tendo dificuldades com o erro **"Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."**. Já mudei o método para `POST`, porém a API só aceita se o método informado for `GET`.

Já tentei enviar o `body` como `header`, e a API também não aceita.

Ao pesquisar vi que para WebRequest não é possível enviar um `body` via o método `GET`. 
Vocês conseguem me ajudar? Segue abaixo o código que estou utilizando em Visual Basic.

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + base64)
request.Method = "GET"
request.ContentType = "application/json"

Dim httpRequest As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(request, HttpWebRequest)

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(body) Then
  Dim requestStream As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
  Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(requestStream, New Text.UTF8Encoding(False))
    sw.Write(body)
  End Using
End If

Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
  Dim responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
  Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(responseStream)
  resultData = sr.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

Comment: Você tem controle sobre essa API para poder alterar dela? Esse método dela PRECISA ser GET? Esse body pode ser passado via parâmetro? Diga qual é o problema inicial: o problema que ao tentar resolver te levou a este problema da pergunta, pois está com cara de [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/144579)

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves, eu não tenho controle sobre essa API para poder altera-lá. O método precisa ser GET. O Body pode ser passado como parâmetro. Eu procurei como enviar via parâmetro usando a classe de HttpWebRequest mas não encontrei nada.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves Essa API é de um fornecedor da empresa que eu trabalho, e preciso enviar um body com uns filtros para que eu receba uma lista de protocolos. O problema real é que fui usar o código informado acima, e recebo o retorno da mensagem de erro: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.